# Cambiar color con un operador ternario en Flutter

Tags: flutter, condiciones, dart, operador-ternario

Tengo una duda, sobre los operadores ternarios en Flutter, Yo tengo que cambiar el color de un container según un valor dado por una variable, Ejemplo

```
color: (b1)? Colors.lightBlue : Colors.redAccent,
```

Con eso me tira un error de:

```
Invalid constant value.dart(invalid_constant)
```

Agradezco de ante mano cualquier ayuda.
Aclaraciones: b1 es un booleano

Comment: por qué encierras en parentesis el "b1"?

Comment: Lo vi en You Tube y lo deje así sin querer

Answer (score 2):

Dado tu ejemplo veo que `b1` es una variable booleana:

```
bool b1 = false;
```

para hacer la validación únicamente tienes que aplicar los operadores ternarios, sin la variable `b1` en paréntesis:

```
color: b1 ? Colors.lightBlue : Colors.redAccent
```

A raíz de esto no veo algún otro problema.

Si te sigue apareciendo el error, muy probablemente sea porque el `Widget` que contiene la propiedad `color` ha sido asignado como `const`, para esto solo tienes que removerlo.

Comment: era lo de const, viendo tu respuesta me di cuenta, muchas gracias

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta, te pido que la marques como correcta, para que así puedas ayudar a otras personas con el mismo problema

Comment: De casualidad dabes como cambiar el JVM de .gradlew en visual studio code?